# Why does gcc choose the most basic memset() implementation?

Tags: c, gcc, libc, memset

My bare-metal program manually calls `memset()` to zero entire/aligned 4k pages like this (I'm not using uint64_t, but another 8-byte thing):

```
  uint64_t something[512] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));
  memset(something, 0x0, 4096);
```

I'm compiling similar to this...

```
%> /path/to/gcc-11.1.0/bin/aarch64-unknown-elf-gcc \
     -O3 \
     -std=gnu99 \
     -nostartfiles \
     --specs=nano.specs \
     -march=armv8.1-a \
     -Wl,--gc-sections \
     -Tlinker_script.lds \
     my_code.c \
     -o my_code.elf
```

When I disassemble and look at `memset()` that is linked in, it's this basic/generic/one-byte-at-a-time, implementation:

```
000000004010399c <memset>:
      s = (char*)aligned_addr;
    }

#endif /* not PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED */

  while (n--)
    4010399c:   d2800003    mov x3, #0x0                    // #0
    401039a0:   eb03005f    cmp x2, x3
    401039a4:   54000041    b.ne    401039ac <memset+0x10>  // b.any
    *s++ = (char) c;

  return m;
}
    401039a8:   d65f03c0    ret
    *s++ = (char) c;
    401039ac:   38236801    strb    w1, [x0, x3]
    401039b0:   91000463    add x3, x3, #0x1
    401039b4:   17fffffb    b   401039a0 <memset+0x4>
```

I'm expecting an aarch64 optimized version that uses `stp` or vector instructions.  My compiler has a `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/newlib-nano` subdirectory.

I've removed `--specs=nano.specs` and fiddled around with a variety of options, but I'm not sure what I can do here...

*HOW CAN I GET THE OPTIMIZED `memset()` IMPLEMENTATION*?

> Note that I used `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/bin/aarch64-unknown-elf-ar x` to extract the `libc_a.memset.o` file from lots of different `*.a` files, but they were all empty: `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/newlib-nano/aarch64-unknown-elf/lib/libc.a`, `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/newlib-nano/aarch64-unknown-elf/lib/libc_nano.a`, `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/newlib-nano/aarch64-unknown-elf/lib/libg.a`, `/path/to/gcc-11.1.0/aarch64-unknown-elf/lib/libc.a`, etc...  Not the byte-by-byte implementation, just empty. I did this to look for a good implementation, but I clearly don't understand what is going on here...

Comment: How does GCC know that `something` is page-aligned?  Have you told it that it is?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes. "something" above is declared with "__attribute__((aligned(4096)))".  In the disassembly, I verify the alignment.

Comment: I don't think the compiler would pick another function implementation based on the attribute of an operand. Well, `memset` probably *could* be implemented in a way that it checks the alignment and choosing the algorithms, but it is up to the C standard library implementation you are using, and not the compiler. I saw such implementations in ARMCC libraries, but these were surprisingly buggy...

Comment: wasn't llibrary compiler with  PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED?

Comment: I didn't build the compiler, but I am pretty sure no one anywhere used -DPREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED or whatever...

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte I see it in the disassembly. I know that you did not use it. It was used by someone who compiled the code. See the `#endif` Find the glibc source code and recompile

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, because I didn't think it was important at the time.  I'll edit it to show the declaration of "something"...

Comment: Minor nitpick: why do you use the non-standard and GCC-specific aligned attribute when you could be using the alignof() macro which is part of standard C11?

Comment: @JohnScott, because I am providing code to people that have standardized on C99, although they do allow some gnu extensions...  Sigh...  I am also stuck on C++11 for another part of this project.  Sigh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the code here. Your library was compiled with the definition  `PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED`. You need to recompile your library.

https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/string/memset.c

```
/*
FUNCTION
    <<memset>>---set an area of memory
INDEX
    memset
ANSI_SYNOPSIS
    #include <string.h>
    void *memset(void *<[dst]>, int <[c]>, size_t <[length]>);
TRAD_SYNOPSIS
    #include <string.h>
    void *memset(<[dst]>, <[c]>, <[length]>)
    void *<[dst]>;
    int <[c]>;
    size_t <[length]>;
DESCRIPTION
    This function converts the argument <[c]> into an unsigned
    char and fills the first <[length]> characters of the array
    pointed to by <[dst]> to the value.
RETURNS
    <<memset>> returns the value of <[dst]>.
PORTABILITY
<<memset>> is ANSI C.
    <<memset>> requires no supporting OS subroutines.
QUICKREF
    memset ansi pure
*/

#include <string.h>

#define LBLOCKSIZE (sizeof(long))
#define UNALIGNED(X)   ((long)X & (LBLOCKSIZE - 1))
#define TOO_SMALL(LEN) ((LEN) < LBLOCKSIZE)

_PTR
_DEFUN (memset, (m, c, n),
    _PTR m _AND
    int c _AND
    size_t n)
{
  char *s = (char *) m;

#if !defined(PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED) && !defined(__OPTIMIZE_SIZE__)
  int i;
  unsigned long buffer;
  unsigned long *aligned_addr;
  unsigned int d = c & 0xff;    /* To avoid sign extension, copy C to an
                   unsigned variable.  */

  while (UNALIGNED (s))
    {
      if (n--)
        *s++ = (char) c;
      else
        return m;
    }

  if (!TOO_SMALL (n))
    {
      /* If we get this far, we know that n is large and s is word-aligned. */
      aligned_addr = (unsigned long *) s;

      /* Store D into each char sized location in BUFFER so that
         we can set large blocks quickly.  */
      buffer = (d << 8) | d;
      buffer |= (buffer << 16);
      for (i = 32; i < LBLOCKSIZE * 8; i <<= 1)
        buffer = (buffer << i) | buffer;

      /* Unroll the loop.  */
      while (n >= LBLOCKSIZE*4)
        {
          *aligned_addr++ = buffer;
          *aligned_addr++ = buffer;
          *aligned_addr++ = buffer;
          *aligned_addr++ = buffer;
          n -= 4*LBLOCKSIZE;
        }

      while (n >= LBLOCKSIZE)
        {
          *aligned_addr++ = buffer;
          n -= LBLOCKSIZE;
        }
      /* Pick up the remainder with a bytewise loop.  */
      s = (char*)aligned_addr;
    }

#endif /* not PREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED */

  while (n--)
    *s++ = (char) c;

  return m;
}
```

Comment: I think you're right.  I didn't compile the compiler (or the newlib library that resides below the compiler).  Hmm...

Comment: It's a little sad that at compile time I cannot choose whether I want speed or size.  That choice has to be made at the time the compiler/library were built...